# Where to find information about tests from Phoronix test suite?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, xen, benchmark

[Phoronix Test Suite](http://www.phoronix-test-suite.com/) is a linux benchmarking tool made of tests and suites of tests.

To print all available test

```
phoronix-test-suite list-available-tests
```

To print all available suites

```
phoronix-test-suite list-available-suites
```

However, how can I get detailed information about the tests and suites? I need to choose the most appropriate tests to benchmark Qubes OS (based on paravirtualized XeN hypervisor) against a non-virtualized linux distribution.

I probably need synthetic benchmarks to measure the specific performance bottlenecks.

The only information I can find is, whether it is graphic/processor/system/disk test.

Comment: You could try the [official documentation](http://www.phoronix-test-suite.com/documentation/phoronix-test-suite.pdf) or their forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information about [Tests](https://openbenchmarking.org/tests/pts) and test [Suites](https://openbenchmarking.org/suites/pts) is at [OpenBenchmarking.com](https://openbenchmarking.org). The website has been [redesigned completely](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=pts-62-ob&num=1) recently to collaborate with the upcoming [Phoronix Test Suite 6.4](http://www.phoronix-test-suite.com/?k=downloads) and to offer advanced information about the tests in a neat and comprehensive way .